# JavaScript: Load Images in a div after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, image, web, load

I have a hidden div (by using max-height and transition) that show up when I click a button. This div contains several images that load up when you first load the site. I would like them to load when I click the button to show the div, to make the site lighter.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .class1 {
      max-height:0px;
      transition:max-height 1s;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function show() {
      document.getElementById('id1').style.maxHeight = "200px";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="show()">Show Images</button>
  <hr>
 
  <div id="id1" class="class1">
    <img src="img1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img4.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
 
  <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use lazy loading and load them accordingly, it will help in improvising performence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest using an attribute on the img tags to store the intended src attribute, then apply it on the button click. This would avoid having to maintain a list of src urls in your JavaScript.

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById('id1').style.maxHeight = "200px";
  var images = document.querySelectorAll("#id1 img");
  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
  {
    images[i].src = images[i].getAttribute('data-src');
  }
}
```

```css
.class1 {
  max-height:0px;
  transition:max-height 1s;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show()">Show Images</button>
<hr>
    
<div id="id1" class="class1">
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="">
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="">
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="">
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="">
</div>
    
<hr>
```

Comment: @joe this works for me but if I put in my own images, it only displays the first and can't goto the next.  If i get rid of the height then you can see them all but why won't it rotate through them?  I assume something with it being done locally compared to going through the lorempixel images.

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing your code. It could potentially be a styling conflict with something else in your code. The method of showing the images here is arbritrary, you could just as easily [use display css property](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp) instead. If you are unable to find a solution I recommend posting your own question to stackoverflow, it's more likely you will get responses from more people.

Comment: The code pen does not work for me in Chrome

Comment: @G M Thanks for letting me know. The image urls were down. I've converted to a code snippet with new image urls.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6ve7ub79/

You can do it easily using jQuery

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').bind('click', function(){
$('.i1').attr('src', 'img1.jpg');
$('.i2').attr('src', 'img2.jpg');
$('.i3').attr('src', 'img3.jpg');
$('.i4').attr('src', 'img4.jpg');
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="show()">Show Images</button>
<hr>
<div id="id1" class="class1">
<img class="i1" src="" alt="">
<img class="i2" src="" alt="">
<img class="i3" src="" alt="">
<img class="i4" src="" alt="">
</div>
<hr>
```

**CSS**

```
.class1 {
  transition:max-height 1s;
}
```

Comment: I needed something more generic to handle a large number of images, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .class1 {
      max-height:0px;
      transition:max-height 1s;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function show() {
      document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML= '<img src="img1.jpg" alt=""><img src="img2.jpg" alt=""><img src="img3.jpg" alt=""><img src="img4.jpg" alt="">';
      document.getElementById('id1').style.maxHeight = "200px";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="show()">Show Images</button>
  <hr>

  <div id="id1" class="class1">

  </div>

  <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works in the example but the actual code is more complicated. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you can call seprate file  in iframe

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .class1 {
      max-height:0px;
      transition:max-height 1s;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function show() {
      document.getElementById('id1').style.maxHeight = "200px";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="show()">Show Images</button>
  <hr>
 
  <div id="id1" class="class1">
    <img src="img1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img4.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
 
  <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code, also provide an explanation for what the code is doing.